# How to pass an array of objects to a button?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I have two classes: one called `Student` and the other one called `Course`. I would like to make a simulation for a simple registration system.

My `Student` class part has the following form:

```
class Student
{
    private String id,
    private Course[] listOfCourses;
    private int numCourse;
    //accesing methods
    public registration(Course course){
          listOfCourses[numCourse]=course;
          numCourse++;
    }
    public Course[] getCourse(){
          return listOfCourses;
    }
}
```

and the `Course` class has the following form:

```
class Course
{
     String id, String courseName;
     //constructor
     //accesing methods
}
```

I would like that by pressing a buttom in a form made in Java Swing, to display the contents of the courses registered by one specific student into a jTable. I have tried the following, but with no results at all:

```
Student e=new Student();
Course d[]=new Course[4];   
d=e.getCourses();    //to receive the array of Courses from the Student class
for (int i=0;i<d.length;i++){
      jTable2.setValueAt(estLista[i].getName(), i, 0);
}
```

how I can do that? I mean there is a way in which I could get the contents of the array, that is stored in the `Course` class, into the `ActionEvent` of the button?

Comment: what problem are you having exactly?

Comment: @MrD, the problem that I have is that I am not receiving the array of Courses in a way that I can put their contents in a Jtable

Comment: but do you want to have a complete UI for registration? or just a button for registration with hardcoded data inside your application?

Comment: the behavior of the button is just to print the courses that one student is taking

Answer (score 1):

From the code you have provided I believe there atleast one reason why you are not getting the courses.. because it is not set in registration process:) (Also the syntax is not correct unless you have a registration class?) This might not be a complete solution but it corrects one of the problem

```
public void registration(Course course){
     // listOfCourses[numCourse];
        listOfCourses[numCourse]=course;
      numCourse++;
}
```

Comment: sorry it was one typo that I made, anyway it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it is not too clear for me yet, but I will put some code and tell me if it helps you.

**Note: Not tested**

For Student (sorry I prefer to use lists instead of arrays):

```
public class Student {

    private String id;
    private List<Course> takenCourses;

    public void registration(Course course){
        if (this.takenCourses != null) {
            takenCourses.add(course);
        } else {
            System.err.println("an array has not been specified.");
        }
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Course> getTakenCourses() {
        return takenCourses;
    }
    public void setTakenCourses(List<Course> takenCourses) {
        this.takenCourses = takenCourses;
    }
```

For course:

```
public class Course {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

For your UI, I just created a "simulation" of UI, I assume you have implemented something more complete... I assume you have intialized the components as global variables for your frame or panel or at least you have methods to get them.

```
public class UIHelper extends JFrame {

    Student student = new Student();
    JButton btnAction;
    JTable myTable;
    public UIHelper() {
        //Methods for creating UI 
        //.
        //.
        //.
        student.setId("stackoverflowed");
        student.setTakenCourses(new ArrayList<Course>());

        btnAction = new JButton("Action!");
        //Methods of the JButton (...)
        btnAction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //Now just process since student is a global variable (you can set it static as well) but it shouldn't be a good practice at all
                for (Course course : student.getTakenCourses()) {
                    System.out.println(course.getName());
                             //Add the element to your table.
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Assume this is your UI
        new UIHelper();
    }
```

Hope I give you an idea, best regards.